# Custom controls Android

Tags: android

I have passed few online courses on Android. And started my first project. Currently i'm stuck on creating my own Widget.

I cannot find any information on how to override default control styles or how to group default controls into custom control. The problem is:

When we create extend an Activity there is a method onCreated where we point which XML layout to use. In my opinion in the same way custom controls should be created.

For example, i want to create a control, that will have ImageView and some buttons, which type will depend on data coming from the server ( email button, skype button or any other )

So i created a class:

```
public class InteractiveHeaderControl extends View {

    public InteractiveHeaderControl(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

I created a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_stack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**So the question is, how can i apply this layout to my control and poulate the button_stack in runtime?**

For example in code i want to create this control, like:

```
InteractiveHeaderControl control = new InteractiveHeaderControl(List<button>);
```

and in control constructor handle the passed parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Layout instead of a view. Here is a example:

```
public class DefaultHeading extends FrameLayout {        

    public DefaultHeading(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.default_heading, this, true);

        addView(view);
    }
```

And if you want to use some attributes:

Add this to res->values->attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="awesomeedit">
        <attr name="regex" format="string"/>
        <attr name="name" format="string"/>
        <attr name="hint" format="string"/>
        <attr name="error" format="string"/>
        <attr name="required" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="link" format="string"/>
        <attr name="email" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="number" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="password" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

use it in your layout file:

```
<yourpackage.DefaultHeading
... 

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:error="@string/not_valid_email_msg"
...
>
```

Get values:

```
 public class DefaultHeading extends FrameLayout {  



    public DefaultHeading(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);


 TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.awesomeedit, 0, 0);
        String name;
        String regex;
        String hint;
        String error;
        String link;
        try {
            name = ta.getString(R.styleable.awesomeedit_name);
            regex = ta.getString(R.styleable.awesomeedit_regex);
            hint = ta.getString(R.styleable.awesomeedit_hint);
            error = ta.getString(R.styleable.awesomeedit_error);
            link = ta.getString(R.styleable.awesomeedit_link);
            required = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.awesomeedit_required, false);
            email = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.awesomeedit_email, false);
            password = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.awesomeedit_password, false);
            nummber = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.awesomeedit_number, false);
        } finally {
            ta.recycle();
        }
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.default_heading, this, true);

        addView(view);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how to do it.
For start read:

1. [How to create custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)
2. [How to create custom views in general](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

First, you should rather create a custom `ViewGroup` instead of a custom `View`. 
I advice not to pass the `List` of actuall view instances (in your case `Buttons`) through your constructor, but better to just pass some information (title, what to do after click,...) and then build your buttons in the component itself..